# Why am I getting a null value from the Post method on a Web API Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I have a pretty simple WebAPI class, that returns JSON for my **Get** methods.  My **Post** method is:

```
    // POST: api/Diff
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(value);
    }
```

and I'm calling both methods from a console application:

```
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            // New code:
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:50541/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            // New code:
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/diff/1");
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var diff = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Diff>();
                Console.WriteLine("{0}\t${1}", diff.Text, diff.Revision);
            }

            var blah = new Diff() { Text = "Gizmo", Revision = 999};
            response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/diff", blah);
```

The **Get** call works. I verified in the debugger that before the 
PostAsJson method is callled that *blah* is not null.  However in the debugger on the API's post method, *value* is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method is expecting a `string`:

```
public void Post([FromBody]string value)
```

And you're sending it a `Diff`:

```
var blah = new Diff() { Text = "Gizmo", Revision = 999};
response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/diff", blah);
```

So...

Either change it to expect a `Diff`:

```
public void Post([FromBody]Diff value)
```

**Or** send it a string:

```
response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/diff", new { value = "some string" });
```

Answer (score 2):

You send to the controller a complex object:

```
var blah = new Diff() { Text = "Gizmo", Revision = 999};
```

but your controller expects that in the request's body there is only one string with name "value":

```
public void Post([FromBody]string value)
```

A possible solution is to change the parameter of the `Post` method to the `Diff` object:

```
public void Post([FromBody]Diff diff)
```